# Add img attribute in paragraph in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In Laravel, this works:

...inside AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    $content = [
>      '<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p> 
>       <p><img src='img/image.jpg'></p>
>       <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>'
    ];

    view::share('content', $content);
}
```

...then in my blade view;

```
<div>
    {!! $content !!}
</div>
```

Tell me please, how will I make this work with Vue.js in Laravel? Thank you. (Please respect)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `v-html` directive which allows you to parse raw HTML.

[Official Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

```
<div v-html="{{$content}}"></div>
```

**Changes**

(Ensure Image Exists)
`<img src='img/image.jpg'>` to `<img src="img/image.jpg">`

`view::share('content', $content);` to `View::share('content', $content);`

At the top of your AppServiceProvider add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

Comment: the texts are visible but the image isn't.  And I've used this instead -- "<p v-html="content"> </p>".  The one you've shared is giving me an error.

Comment: It's not error-error per se` but the thing is, texts are visible but the image also has the output as text like this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet......

<img src='img/image.jpg'>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet......


And also, I'm using vue so I don't want to trouble of fetching it from AppServiceProvider. I've tried doing it but I'm getting an error.  Perhaps you can enlighten me more if I'd be using AppService. Furthermore, I always put use "Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;" at the top of AppServiceProvider.  Thank you.